# ERROR with RDD.registerAsTable?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to run sql queries with pyspark. I am using the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
import os

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Project_SQL")
sc = SparkContext(conf = spark_config)
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").option(url="..."
                                   , driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                                   , dbtable = "UDM_CDS.TRANSACTIONS"
                                   , user="..."
                                   , password="...").load()


df_rdd = df.rdd
df_rdd.registerAsTable("transactions")
sqlctx.sql('SELECT TRANSACTION_KEY FROM transactions').show(5)
```

But it keeps saying that RDD object has no atributte registerAsTable, while it has! I'm confused! 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @philantrovert pointed out the correct function is `registerTempTable`

dataframes have a `registerTempTable` attribute (you can convert them to spark sql) but RDDs do not (it's not a structured table).

Just use :

```
df.registerTempTable("transactions")
```

Since it's already loaded as a dataframe.

If you want a permanent table in your database, use `.write.saveAsTable("transactions")`

Comment: *`registerTempTable`

Comment: At first I did so but still had the same error with saying DataFrame object has no attribute registerAsTable!

Comment: you can also mention that in newer version `registerTempTable` has been marked as deprecated. Alternative is `createOrReplaceTempView`